# How to draw a Polygon (triangle and pentagon) with a mouse?

Tags: java, awt, polygon

How can I find xpoints[] and ypoints[], if I want to draw a polygon with the mouse, using getX() and getY() ?

My code at the moment is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Poligonos extends Figura{
    public void Poligonos (int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints){
        //private int[] xPoints = {(x1/2), x1, (x1+(x1/2))}  // {(getX()/2), getX(), (getX()+(getX()/2))};
        //private int[] yPoints = {( y1 + y1 ), y1 ,( y1 + y1 )};

    }
    @Override   
    public void desenha(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(cor);
        g.drawPolygon(  xPoints, yPoints, 3);
    }
    @Override
    public void setCoordenadas(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        p.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
        p.y = Math.min(y1, y2);

        int xPoints[] = {(p.x /2), p.x , ( p.x +( p.x /2))};  // {(getX()/2), getX(), (getX()+(getX()/2))};
        int yPoints[] = {( p.y + p.y ), p.y ,( p.y + p.y )};
    }
}
```

And getX() and getY() part is:

```
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           x1 = e.getX();
           y1 = e.getY();
       }

       @Override
       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
           x2 = e.getX();
           y2 = e.getY();
           r.setCoordenadas(x1, y1, x2, y2);
           pEdicao.repaint();
       }
```

How can I make this work? I just want draw a pentagon and a triangle with mouse.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could define a Shape using a Path2D and use a AffineTransform to change its size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a setup where you do something like

```
int numCoordinates = /*(get the number of coordinates by getting number of clicks after a certain action, etc.)*/
int[] xCords = new int[numCoordinates];
int[] yCords = new int[numCoordinates];


xCords[index] = e.getX();
yCords[index] = e.getY();
index++;

if(index > numCoordinates){
    index = 0;
    pEdicao.repaint();
}
```

Comment: But I just want one mouse click, for draw, like a paint in windows.
In pain I chose 1 point, press this point, move mouse, and get a polygon.
[link](http://prntscr.com/9ggwj1)

Thanks for you helping me, I appreciate it.